# Roadmap - Guitar

Tags: theory, guitar

I have been playing guitar (acoustic) for a long time.
I have the basics of musical theory. And I have good guitar skills.
I studied on my own, so I didn't have a clear learning structure. Now faced with gaps in knowledge - theoretical and practical. I have to go back to the beginning :(

Is there an order (structure) for learning?
Stages of development?
Musician/guitarist roadmap?
As in IT?

### Roadmap example:

[image: Roadmap Python]

Comment: Step 1: Buy one of the 500-Zillion books answering this exact question.

Comment: Not a clue where in the world you are, but first check any exam board curricula as they are designed to test knowledge in a graded manner, and will furnish you with that roadmap, from beginner to advanced. Won't recommend any, but in UK there are some, whose info. can be found by Googling.

Comment: I spent 25 years working in IT and only now have I ever heard of a roadmap for IT. Same with guitar, except that’s 30 years.

Comment: @Aaron, My question is probably too general.
I just want to find specific gaps in my knowledge, and not look for them in books by re-reading too much literature.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I have been working in IT for over 4 years, but I have not used the roadmap. I do not get the point of it. But if someone did the same for the guitar, it would be easier to find your level.

Comment: If you don't get the point of the roadmap for Python (I don't get it too), why do you ask for the same thing for music? The problem with this roadmap, as well as with music, is that you have many quite weakly linked "topics" that cannot be ordered in any particular fashion. For instance, harmonics often seem to be classified as an "advanced" technique, but you can learn them in ~ 5 minutes no matter your level.

Comment: @Ramillies, Will explain. If I do not understand something in python, the roadmap will not help me, I, with any level of programming, can find an article, documentation or tutorial to solve the problem. The guitar is more difficult.

Comment: @Ramillies, Just because I can play any chord doesn't mean I can play the blues.

Comment: Like @ToddWilcox - I've been playing instruments for 40-something years, and in IT related fields for 30-something. A roadmap like that would definitely not work for me - and I have not seen one that would, as there is not a single way to do any of this

Comment: Hire a teacher. After looking through this roadmap concept I think with guitar (and probably other things), the correct roadmap will be catered to where you are at and what you want to learn. There won’t be one roadmap for everyone. However, a teacher is someone who has an understanding of most of the body of knowledge for guitar and can cater what you learn and in what order to your goals and needs. If you want to address gaps in your knowledge, a teacher is the best way.

Comment: Not heard of 'roadmaps', for IT or anything, except not owning a satnav, in reality.  But my point still remains - use the 'roadmap' that exam boards have created - or as oft quoted here - go to a teacher, who can assess what you already know, and join the dots, so to speak, thus obviating the need for this mystical 'roadmap'  which it appears from other comments  is just that - mythical. Having played for many years, it becomes apparent where the gaps are, so should be not-so-onerous to find info. to fill those gaps.

Comment: You would do better to ask specific individual questions about the things you don’t understand or the dots you can’t connect here on this site than to ask for an all encompassing formula. An example might be: “How are V7 chords and dim7 chords similar and different from each other?” Like Aaron said, there are more than a few books out there, some of which think they are teaching you everything you need to know but we don’t recommend books here. Todd says hire a teacher. This is good advice because a teacher will be able to assess where you are and help you fill in the gaps in your knowledge.

Comment: I thank everyone here, regardless of the closed question. I have enough information to move on. Special thanks to Tim, great idea!